# Using JSON_EXTRACT with nested dictionaries in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I have the following MySQL code:

```
SET @req= "2022-02-15 08:49:11,218 INFO  log_request {'user': 'iamuser', 'endpoint': 'test/endpoint', 'payload': 'a'}";

SELECT
JSON_EXTRACT(REPLACE((SUBSTR(@req,43)),"'", '"'), "$.user") as username,
JSON_EXTRACT(REPLACE((SUBSTR(@req,43)),"'", '"'), "$.endpoint") as path,
JSON_EXTRACT(REPLACE((SUBSTR(@req,43)),"'", '"'), "$.payload") as payload

FROM table_name
LIMIT 1;
```

which returns the following:

```
username: iamuser
endpoint: testendpoint
payload: a
```

However, when I change the payload to be a dictionary within @req, the query doesn't work anymore and returns null:

```
SET @req= "2022-02-15 08:49:11,218 INFO  log_request {'user': 'iamuser', 'endpoint': 'test/endpoint', 'payload': {'a': 'b'}}";
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your line of data is not valid JSON. JSON uses double quotes rather than single. And, JSON parsers are really picky for the sake of security.

If it were

```
{"user": "iamuser", "endpoint": "test/endpoint", "payload": {"a": "b"}}
```

things might work better.

Comment: to fix the issue of single quotes, I use REPLACE as shown in the query. Shouldn't this take care of it?